# Get 3 last tweets using PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I have a fairly simple task and well. I don't know how to get the result I am after.

I have found some code online that looks like:

```
<?php

function parse_feed($feed) {
 $stepOne = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);
 $stepTwo = explode("</content>", $stepOne[1]);
 $tweet = $stepTwo[0];
 $tweet = html_entity_decode($tweet);
 return $tweet;
}

function showTwitter($username) {
$feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=1";
 $twitterFeed = file_get_contents($feed);
 return stripslashes(parse_feed($twitterFeed));
}

echo showTwitter("brandrally");

?>
```

It works nicely in that it returns **one** Result, e.g.

```
@<a class=" " href="https://twitter.com/jackie_elliott1">jackie_elliott1</a> Best of luck for tomorrow!
```

What I actually want is to retrieve the last **three tweets** from our timeline and output them into separate div's or li's. e.g.

```
<li>tweet 1</li>
<li>tweet 2</li>
<li>tweet 3</li>
```

It seems straight forward though I just don't know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Paul

Comment: Can you check `var_dump($twitterFeed );` before dojing any operation on it.

Answer (score 2):

Some idea's for you:

```
<script src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
(function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); 
   e.type = 'text/javascript';
  e.async = true;
    e.src = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE.json?
callback=twitterCallback2&count=3';
   document.getElementById('twitter_update_list').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `&count=3` to your `$feed` URL?

Comment: Hi - Pritaeas, Tried adjusting the &rpp=1 to 3 and it still throws me just one tweet.

Comment: I suggested adding `count`, not changing `rpp`.